# Instagram API RequestToken URL?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, oauth-2.0, instagram

I am using GTM OAuth Library to integrate Instagram into my app. The GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch init method's signature looks like this:

```
- (id)initWithScope:(NSString *)scope
           language:(NSString *)language
    requestTokenURL:(NSURL *)requestURL
  authorizeTokenURL:(NSURL *)authorizeURL
     accessTokenURL:(NSURL *)accessURL
     authentication:(GTMOAuthAuthentication *)auth
     appServiceName:(NSString *)keychainAppServiceName
           delegate:(id)delegate
   finishedSelector:(SEL)finishedSelector;
```

What I am stuck at is the `requestTokenURL`. The instagram docs list the `access/authorize tokenURL`, but they don't mention anything about `requestTokenURL`. Any one have any idea what this url is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram use OAuth 2.0, not OAuth 1.0. The `requestTokenURL` is part of OAuth 1.0. If you're using `GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch` you're probably using the wrong version of the library, as that class doesn't exist in the OAuth 2.0 compliant library from Google.

Try getting http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/ instead.